# Are there any rules to be followed while chanting Devi Kavacham?

Tags: devi, durga, durga-saptasati, kavacha

I used to read the Devi Kavacham from Saptashati daily but stopped as I was unaware of the rules and was not formally initiated into it. Are there any prescribed rules?

Also, can someone share the correct version? I notice a few variations in renditions and available material online.

If Devi Kavacham needs initiation, then is there any shloka or mantra from Durga Saptashati that can be read daily by a female devotee without initiation?

Comment: Although kavacham is a part in angas of Saptshati. But it can be chanted alone too. The only prerequisite is Shauch must be maintained. Devi kavacham doesn't need initiation because it has no Beej Mantra and moreover it belongs from Markandey Purana and not any tantra. Thus, being a Purankot kavacham, everyone is free to chant it. Even Devi saptashloki from Saptshati is open for everyone.